# Data race and Race condition during lazy initializing a SIngleton

Tags: java, multithreading

While reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* book by Brian Goetz, I came across Data races and Race conditions.

**Data races**

> A program is said to have a data race, and therefore not be a
>   "properly synchronized" program, when there is a variable that is read
>   by more than one thread, written by at least one thread, and the write
>   and the reads are not ordered by a happens-before relationship.

**Race condition**

> A race condition occurs when the correctness of a computation depends
>   on the relative timing or interleaving of multiple threads by the
>   runtime; in other words, when getting the correct answer relies on
>   lucky timing. The most common type of race condition is
>   check-then-act, where a potentially stale observation is used to make
>   a decision on what to do next

As I understand, Data race can be avoided by making sure that one or more of the above conditions hold false - ie, by making shared variables immutable or by making the access to them properly `synchronized`.

My question is about the example of a SingletonFactory that is usually given to illustrate **race condition**.

e.g.:

```
public class SingletonFactory {

    private Singleton singleton = null;

    private SingletonFactory() {}

    public Singleton getInstance() {
        if(this.singleton == null) {
            this.singleton = new Singleton();
        }
        return this.singleton;
   }
}
```

Can this code can also be considered to cause a **Data race**?

I understand that one way to make the above program *"completely thread safe"* would be to have a [double checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) and also make the class variable `volatile`.

But in case I just declare the `Singleton` variable `volatile`, but fail to synchronize the code block that initializes the variable, then can it be considered as safe at-least w.r.t "Data race", but still unsafe w.r.t. race condition?  In general I am still in search of a good realistic example where there is no data race, but there is still a potential race condition!

(a [blog](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/490) that is usually referred to explain the difference between data race and race condition does not help me to understand this)

Comment: The above definition for data race sucks. Because it would also consider 2 concurrent writes to the same address being a data race. Which isn't the case because they are synchronizing operations and always ordered. It should explicitly exclude synchronizing operations from the definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three general flavors that are commonly seen with a lazy Singleton.  The first is one without synchronization like your first example.  The second, as you mentioned is double checked locking without volatile, and finally DCL with volatile.  One contains a race-condition (if shared field is synchronized) and one contains a data-race.

```
public static class Singleton{
   private static volatile Singleton INSTANCE; // volatile to illustrate the race condition

   public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new Singleton();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

In this case there doesn't happen to be a data-race but **there is a race condition**.  The race here is that two or more threads can create a Singleton instance.

Now for a Double Checked locking example:

```
public static class Singleton{
   private static Singleton INSTANCE; // not volatile to illustrate the data-race

   public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            synchronized(Singleton.class){
                 INSTANCE = new Singleton();
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

In this case there **is a data-race** but not race-condition.  The writes that occur to the INSTANCE variable may not be visible to other threads despite INSTANCE not being null.

So to answer your question.

> My question is whether this code can also be considered to cause a
>   Data race?

In your example, it contains both a data-race and a race-condition since neither the shared mutable variable is synchronized nor the atomic action of check-then-set is synchronized.

Comment: thanks for the reply(+1). Would you say `volatile` is a necessary and sufficient condition to avoid **Data race** in `Java`?

Comment: @zencv In single assignment single reads it would be.  But consider a situation where you have a volatile field that is already assigned.  Any updates to that field, for instance maybe `person.setName(..)`, could still cause a data-race.  Even though person is volatile it doesn't prevent the data-race for `name`.

Comment: Of course if `name` in person is volatile then you are data-race free.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no, it will not be data-safe, because two callers can still end up with two *different* instances for the "singleton".

Data Race is-a Race Condition, but not all Race Conditions are Data Races.

It can also happen that two parallel execution paths compete for an outcome. Consider signals - send SIGHUP *and* SIGTERM to one and the same process. What will happen? In what order? The behaviour will (often) be non-deterministic, even if there is no explicitly shared data between the executions.